# An Asynchronously Populated List

Tags: java

I have to implement an interface which returns a `List`:

```
List<Foo> getAllTheFoos()
```

The `Foo`s come from a DB, and there may be a lot of them. I know exactly how many there will be before I make the query. Once `getAllTheFoos` returns them, the caller will do something involving IO with each `Foo` in turn. (Obviously it would have been better for the function to return an `Iterator` or similar, but that's by the by.)

I think that I can improve performance by loading the `List` in the background. As I expect the caller to access the `List` sequentially, it should be able to consume many of the items while the query is running (assuming that the query doesn't, for instance, spend a lot of time sorting the data up front before returning anything.)

My code for this is below.

I'd be interested in feedback on:

1. Is the cross thread visibility of data correct? When one thread does `contents[i] = x` is that visible correctly to other threads?
2. Is there any race condition where a client may end up stuck in `get()`?
3. What's a better name for `InitialiserAccess`?
4. Is there a better way of propagating an `Exception` from the initialising thread to the client?
5. Any other comments.

```java
package foo;

import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class LazyArrayList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
    private final T[] contents;
    private volatile RuntimeException error;

    public LazyArrayList(int capacity, Consumer<InitialiserAccess> initialiser) {
        contents = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
            try {
                initialiser.accept(new InitialiserAccess());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                synchronized (contents) {
                    error = new RuntimeException("Error initialising list", e);
                    contents.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        synchronized (contents) {
            while (contents[index] == null && error == null) {
                try {
                    contents.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
        if (error != null) {
            throw error;
        }
        return contents[index];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return contents.length;
    }

    public class InitialiserAccess {
        public void set(int i, T item) {
            synchronized(contents) {
                contents[i] = item;
                contents.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        public int size() {
            return contents.length;
        }
    }
}
```

And the unit test:

```java
package foo;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

class LazyArrayListUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testExceptionInitialisingList() throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
        LazyArrayList<Object> list = new LazyArrayList<>(1, initialiser -> {
            try {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            } finally {
                s.release();
            }
        });
        // is this always going to work -- as the release is in the finally above the assignment to the error field hasn't happened yet...
        s.acquire();
        try {
            list.get(0);
            fail("exception expected");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            assertThat(e.getMessage(), Matchers.startsWith("Error initialising list"));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testFillArraySlowly() throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);

        final LazyArrayList<Integer> list = new LazyArrayList<Integer>(10, initializer -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < initializer.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    s.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                initializer.set(i, i);
            }
        });

        CompletableFuture<Integer> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return list.get(9);
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            s.release();
            Thread.sleep(10);
            assertThat(f.isDone(), Matchers.is(i == 9));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 & 2: It looks good. It is a single field synchorized access, nothing complicated. The only thing my static code analyzer complains about is `return contents[index];` because it accesses an otherwise synchronized field from a non-synchronized context. Not that it makes a difference because the data doesn't change once written, it's just being pedantic.

Question 4: The error propagation can give misleading results to the caller, as the client gets an error when getting element N while the error may actually have occurred when loading element N+M. This will be difficult to debug if the exception message does not identify the element that was loaded. Because the exception is possibly stored for a while, the time stamp that gets logged with the exception may not be exactly accurate, again making debugging a bit more difficult.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't hurt to extend the synchronized block to cover the entire get method.